# Php+MySQL read results from a database and return an array of similar objects as JSON Array

Tags: php, arrays, json

User has items.
Each Item has lots of properties (price, date bought, condition, name)

I want to return a json array of all items and their properties

Here is my code:

```
$user_id = $_GET['user_id'];


$query_user_items        = "SELECT product_id FROM user_products WHERE user_id = :user_id";

$item_ids_array = array();
$success = false;

try {
    $sth = $connection->prepare($query_user_items);
    $sth->execute(array(':user_id' => $user_id));   
    $result = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    $success = true;

} catch (PDOException $ex) {

    $response["success"] = $http_response_server_error;
    $response["message"] = $http_message_server_error . " " . $ex;
    die(json_encode($response));
    $connection = null;
}

if ($success) {

    foreach($result as $key=>$value){

        $query_get_item_details = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_id = :product_id";

        $sth = $connection->prepare($qerty_get_item_details);
        $sth->execute(array(':product_id'=> $value));
        $record = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        $item_id                = $record['product_id'];
        $item_name              = $record['product_name'];
        $item_time_added        = $record['product_time_added'];
        $item_description       = $record['product_description'];
        $item_brand             = $record['product_brand'];
        $item_price_aquired     = $record['product_price_aquired'];
        $item_bought_from_place = $record['product_bought_from_place'];

    }

    /*
    $response["success"]                        = $http_response_success;
    $response["item_ids_array"]                 = $new_array;

    echo json_encode($response);
```

Im not very good with php and I dont know what is going to happen at the second iteration (I dont know if Im iterating right as well)

I suppose $item_name will be overwritten with the second item's name, then the third and at the end I will only have only one object? How can I create an array of objects and their infos and then json_encode that?

Also, should I be declaring these variables outside of the foreach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code could be shortened as follow (this way, you don't use any loop):

```
$query = "SELECT p.* FROM user_products u LEFT JOIN products p ON (p.product_id = u.product_id) WHERE u.user_id = :user_id";

try 
{
    $sth = $connection->prepare($query);
    $sth->execute(array(':user_id' => $_GET['user_id']));   
    $response = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
} 
catch (PDOException $ex) 
{
    $response["success"] = $http_response_server_error;
    $response["message"] = $http_message_server_error . " " . $ex;
}
finally
{
    $connection = null;
    echo json_encode($response);
}
```

Then, in your ajax success handler, you can check if success or message is set (if that's the case, then an error occured). Otherwise, it is an array of results and you will loop through it

Comment: question: may I change this: "SELECT p.* FROM user_products u LEFT JOIN products p ON (p.product_id = u.product_id) WHERE u.user_id = :user_id" to "SELECT product_id.* FROM user_products LEFT JOIN products ON (products.product_id = user_products.product_id) WHERE user_products.user_id = :user_id"?

Comment: Do you want only product_id to be returned to ajax ?

Comment: well thats the problem :( what does p.* stand for? I dislike abbreviations, because they make me think extra. I want all columns from the products table, for every product that the certain user has. I wanted to ask is there a way that this query would work without abbreviations. As it stands now, I dont understand it :)

Comment: In this case `p.*` means all columns from `p`. And p is an alias for `products`. Actually, `p.*` and `products.*` are both the same

Comment: Same query without alias: `SELECT products.* FROM user_products LEFT JOIN products ON (products.product_id = user_products.product_id) WHERE user_products.user_id = :user_id`

Comment: actually my user_products table consists of two columns(all foreign keys) - user_id and product_id. my products table has all the different product data. does that change the query? sorry, I've never did joins before...

Comment: Well it does not change anything except if you want to retrieve user data. In this case you will have to join user table

Comment: can I get some additional information from another table product_categories (product_id, category_id)? Should I create another question about this?

Comment: Once again, you will have to join on specific tables. Feel free to post a new question because it is not same context anymore

Comment: thanks for everything :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21646194/can-i-obtain-information-from-several-db-tables-with-one-query-using-join

Answer (score 1):

You don'y want to run a new query with every iteration.
You might want to use a single query to get all the data:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM   user_products AS up
LEFT JOIN products AS p ON p.product_id = up.product_id

WHERE up.user_id = :user_id
```

In the PHP you can collect the data to array:

```
<?php
$data = array();
while($result = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        $data[] = $result;
    }

?><?=json_encode($data)?>
```

Comment: Should be `while(...) { $data[] = $result; }`. Otherwise, previous result is always erased

Comment: Thanks! I have two questions - may I use p and up without the abbreviations, I really hate abbreviations? if so, should I still use those AS statements? Also what is this <?= thing at the end of the code?

Comment: In this case, Yes you can! :)
though you should consider get use to it since you hold same column names in different tables.

the `<?="aaa"?>` is a short way to echo something, equals to `<? echo "aaa"; ?>`

Comment: and  what is the <?= thing there?